# flattr pluggin is non responsive to click

Tags: wordpress, plugins, flattr

My new flattr button is not responsive, I might have done something wrong :

```
<flattr>
title="A swiss guy website"
description="test"
category=text
align=right
</flattr>
```

this comes with these flattr settings

uid : aprekates
category: text
language: en

i get a button image for sure but no response from the website!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using ad block plus. Try to desactivate the pluggin if you have it for your browser.